# delete vs execSQL commands android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I have a database, `SQLiteDatabase db` I am writing a couple private methods in my manager class that will be called by a public method:

```
    public void updateData (MakeabilityModel newData){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {

          reWriteSVTable(db, list);

          db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e){
           //TODO through rollback message?
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        } finally {

          db.endTransaction();
        }

    }
    //Private Methods
    private void clearTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String table){
        db.delete(table, null, null);

    }


    private void reWriteSVTable(SQLiteDatabase db, List<MakeabilityLens> lenses){
        clearTable(db, singleVision);
        ContentValues cv;
        for(int i=0; i<lenses.size(); i++){
            cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(colScreenID, hsID);
            cv.put(colIconID, id);
            cv.put(colRank, hsTotal);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv);     
         }
   }
```

My question is this.. i want to be able to throw sql exceptions  back to the public method so that if there is an exception, it will kill the transaction and rollback ALL data..

it appears that using delete() and insert() methods are cleaner than execSQL() but don't throw sqlExceptions.  execSQL() on the other hand does? do i need to uses execSQL and how do I insure that should it throws an exception in any of the private methods that it will catch it and roll it back in the private method

Answer (score 0):

first of all `execSQL()` throws an exception if the sql string is not valid. that is the exception is on the sql string syntax NOT the sql operation. that is, it will not throw an exception if the sql statement is valid but the operation failed (because of a constraint for example).

So ..

basically the only difference between `execSQL()` and `delete()` is that `delete()` returns the number of rows affected (in your case, the number of deleted rows), but `execSQL()` doesn't.

Note:
for `delete()` to return the number of rows affected, you have to pass any value other than `null` in the where clause parameter. In your case, pass `"1"`.